# Vacuum sucked in some of the grout between tiles, how to fill the gap?

Tags: flooring, tile, floor, grout, ceramic-tile

[image: where the grout used to be]

I was vacuuming these tile floors and the grout came off. Should I fill it with cement? Is it damaging to leave it like this, should I not mop it?

Comment: Tile grout comes in a rainbow of colors, and a specific color is typically picked to coordinate with the tile.  You can get grout color charts from the hardware store.  Clean a small existing section well, then match the color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use cement or thin set. Use maybe a premixed grout (can sometimes be bought in quarts). Use a grout saw to remove some of the other loose grout
2. While the water can seep under easily, there's no danger in mopping. The grout let's water come back up

Comment: okay premixed grout, any other alternative in case i dont find it? also is there a rule against cement or thin set?

Comment: Cement has lousy adhesion and great compressive strength, so if the floor moves you can expect it to pop out or have tiles crack. Thin set mortar is softer, but again binds the tiles together making them prone to break when the floor moves.

Comment: I have something called "white cement" and it's much easier to find here. Local workers also like to use it on everything even grout. Can I use that instead?

Comment: I suppose you could caulk it if it's just that one line